# Displaying sql data in phonegap app via ajax

Tags: php, html, cordova, blackberry-simulator

Good day guys....

I am new to phonegap but trying to learn as much as i can.
I am currently developing a basic app that recieves data from a database and has to output it on a phonegap app.

So far what i have done is as follows:
On a normal browser,everything works as expected,the data is displayed as expected.
when i run, ant blackberry load-simulator via cmd, i can go on the phone browser and get the same results as on a normal browser.

The problem now comes when i go on to the app and try open a page where i want to display the data on,nothing is displayed and i have no idea why.

basically what happens is, a user clicks on a link to go to an artciles page,articles.html,this page has a relation to articles.js, which simply sends an ajax call to a php file,articles.php,which retrieves data from an articles table.

how can i be able to view the data on the app instead of browsers?
here are all my codes.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="articles.js"></script>
    <title> Articles</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">

    <div id="heading" style="background: #dddddd repeat-x" >
       <center><img src="img/logo.png" height="90" width="340" border="ridged"/></center>
        </div>

<div class="content">


<a href="index.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none"> <img src="img/back.png"width="50" value="Back" height="50"/> Back to home</a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

the above is my articles.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './articles.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){alert(data[0].title);//this alerts the tittle of the 1st record
            $('.content').append("<br />");
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                       var code = data[i].title;
                       var desc = data[i].content.substring(0,100);
                       $('.content').append(code+'<br />'+desc+'<br /><br />success');
                   }
        },
        error: function(data){alert(data[0].title);
            $('.content').append("<br />");
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                       var code = data[i].title;
                       var desc = data[i].content.substring(0,100);
                       $('.content').append(code+'<br />'+desc+'<br /><br />error');
                   }
        }
    });
 });
```

the above is my articles.js which sends an ajax call to a php file.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "myDb";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  articles ORDER BY article_id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

this is my articles.php

Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `jsonp` requests are `GET` not `POST`

Comment: @Musa that did not change my problem,but i will read up on the GET and jsonp requests.Thanks

Comment: after 4 days of research and stress,i am still struggling with this issue!
I hope someone who is advanced in this phonegap business could help me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must specify the full url of your PHP file in your AJAX code.
Change this `url: './articles.php',` to something like `url: 'http://localhost/your_app_folder/your_php_file_ajax_processor.php'`. Hope this helps.